# Celery, chord with chunks

Tags: python, celery

Is it possible to run an "on complete" callback on a chunk in celery?

I'm trying to run something like the following in several variations, but it doesn't event start `mytask`

```
celery.chord(mytask.chunks(tuple(queries), 10),
      
when_complete_callback.s(param="it was task X")).apply_async()
```

This code instead runs, but there is no callback:

```
mytask.chunks(tuple(queries), 10).apply_async()
```

In the same way it would be great to know if the task failed (on failure? on_not_complete?)